# Getting elements from Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, shadow-dom

In a project I'm working on, I have an HTML document that is generated via an application and is later passed to a function that converts the HTML to a PDF.

Within the HTML I have textareas to display information that is editable.  When a user edits the information that is currently in the textarea, I want to save that information so that when it is passed to the PDF generator, it is the most current version of the DOM.

After some testing I discovered that the edited version of the textarea's content is in the Shadow DOM.

Is there a way to get that content and place it into the actual DOM?

I'm not doing anything that is explicitly placing the content in there, but using Firebug and WebInspector I can see it as Shadow Content.

Comment: Firebug? But shadow DOM is not enabled by default in Firefox. http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current value with `<textarea>`'s [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) property and put it in the DOM via its [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) property:

```js
function f() {
  var t = document.getElementById('t');
  t.textContent = t.value;
  alert("The resulting DOM is: " + t.parentNode.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id = "t">test</textarea>
</div>
<button onclick="f()">click</button>
```

...assuming the function you call does indeed read its input from the page's DOM. What library is it?

Comment: This is getting the same result as before. I'm using jQuery. I'll post more specific info when I get to my office.

Comment: This ended up being the solution with some changing of exactly HOW the HTML was generated (pointing a textarea attribute directly to the desired script).  This is what I get for trying to embedded HTML into Objective-C for text formatting :\